# when sourcing a bashrc how to get the line number of the error messages

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bashrc, source

Following [this post](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/246949-there-no-bin-folder-inside-installation-directory.html#post842272), I am souring a `bashrc` file inside the WSL2/Ubuntu by:

```
source /usr/share/openfoam/etc/bashrc
```

but I get lots of error messages:

> -bash: /usr/share/openfoam/bin/<someFile>: No such file or directory

now I want to know which line(s) of the original `bashrc` file is causing these errors. I don't want to mess up the script, so preferably if the `source` command has some options to print out the line numbers of the stream output, or is there a way to activate that generally, that would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39768838/4999991), I realized that the `source` command does one job, executing the given file in Bash. Therefore, to get the line numbers one can simply do:

```
bash --debug /path/to/the/file
```

Comment: I agree that it's definitely the best way to get the line numbers, but keep in mind that running a script through `bash /path/to/the/file` is *not* the same as sourcing it.  When you `source` a script, the script is processed *inside* the current shell, and can do things like set environment variables.  When you run it through the `bash` command, it is run in a new environment, and any changes to variables are lost after that shell exits.